# Problema con str.contains() y filtro de columnas

Tags: python

tengo la siguiente duda:

Tengo una carpeta en Google Drive donde actualizaré un DF a medida que llegan planillas excel. Esto será todos los días.

```
ahumada_concat = pd.DataFrame()
for f in datos:
  df = pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name="PRECIOS ")
  ahumada_concat = ahumada_concat.append(df,ignore_index=True)

ahumada_concat.shape
```

Como todos los días llegarán archivos nuevos, cree dos variables que pudieran mantener las fechas del día de hoy y la del día de ayer, para poder utilizarlas de filtro.

```
fecha=str(ahumada_concat['FECHA'].max())
ayer=str(ahumada_concat['FECHA'].max()- datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

Con estas fechas, me gustaria filtrar las columnas que tengan el mismo valor que las variables `fecha` y `ayer`.
Para esto, **FJSevilla** amablemente me ayudó con un código para lograr lo que deseo.

```
ps=pd.pivot_table(ahumada_concat,index='ID_local',columns='FECHA',values ['STOCK','PRECIO'],aggfunc='count')
ps = pd.DataFrame(ps.to_records())
ps['Dif N° Precios']=(ps.iloc[:,2])-(ps.iloc[:,1])
ps['Dif N° Stock']=(ps.iloc[:,4])-(ps.iloc[:,3])
ps.head(5)
```

Mi idea es que cuando tenga que utilizar la funcion iloc, en vez de buscar las columnas como aparece en el código, quiero que tome las fechas `fecha` y `ayer`, como me lo sugirió FJSevilla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
***Perdón por no ponerlo como código, no supe como hacerlo bien***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo necesito especificamente es reemplazar la linea

```
tabla2['% CS Ayer']=(tabla2.iloc[:,1]/(tabla2.iloc[:,2]+tabla2.iloc[:,1]))*100
```

por algo como

`ahumada_concat[ahumada_concat.columns[pd.Series(ahumada_concat.columns).str.contains(f"{fecha}|{ayer}")`

Sin embargo, al usar el último código me aparece solamente el número de filas, sin mostrar ninguna columna.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando hago el código con otra palabra, funciona de inmediato, como por ejemplo con:

`ahumada_concat[ahumada_concat.columns[pd.Series(ahumada_concat.columns).str.contains('PRODUCTO*')==True]]`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Victor, sería recomendable que agregaras el contenido del DataFrame inicial (cabeceras y algunas líneas) para crear un [mcve]. Pero debes pegarlo como texto, no como una imagen para poder reproducirlo.

Comment: Hola de nuevo Victor, haz `ahumada_concat.head(2)` justo antes de intentar usar `str,contain` y lo que te muestre copia y pégalo como tal en la pregunta a ver si podemos ver que está pasando.

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla, traté de dejarlo lo más completo posible

Comment: Victor ten en cuenta que en ahumada_concat no tienes ninguna columna con fechas por lo que str.contain no te retornará nombre de columna alguna, como si hace con PRODUCTO que si tienes dos columnas que lo contienen. tabla2 si que tiene columnas con fechas en el nombre.

Comment: De cualquier forma, si no me he perdido podrias filtrar ahumada_concat y quedarte solo con las filas cuya fecha sea la de hoy o la de ayer y luego pivotar, con lo que las columnas ya quedarían filtradas como quieres.

Comment: Intentaré hacerlo de la forma que me dices. Por otro lado, en ahumada_concat, la penúltima columna es fecha. Cuando hago una pivot table, queda con el formato de la segunda imagen. Gracias por toda tu ayuda FJSevilla